# error while trying to import the imputer module

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm getting this error while trying to import the imputer module

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

Error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-40d42fb5b303> in <module>
      1 # Import the Imputer module
----> 2 from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
      3 from sklearn.svm import SVC
      4 
      5 # Setup the Imputation transformer: imp

ImportError: cannot import name 'Imputer' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' (C:\Users\MOSTAFA\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html

```
New in version 0.20: SimpleImputer replaces the previous sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer estimator which is now removed.
```

So, beginning with sklearn 0.20 you need to use SimpleImputer instead.

try: `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback your answer solved my problem

Comment: Is there any possibility to get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'" due to versions of sklearn? I'm using Python venv in Vscode with a Jupyter notebook (with kernel this venv created) and I can´t run "from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer". Any idea about this? :) Thanks

Comment: I think that you could have mixed up several python environment and don't have sklearn in this specific environment. Try to install it again in this environment :)